# Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими

Tags: согласование

Допустимо ли в следующем предложении множественное число сказуемого "являются"? Обычно в препозиции сказуемого используется единственное число, но тут еще причастный оборот за двумя подлежащими. Может быть, можно написать "Одними из важных этапов"?

Одним из важных технологических этапов являются покраска шарового крана и нанесение средств антикоррозийной защиты, снижающие возможность возникновения сколов и царапин на поверхности изделия, а также предотвращающие возникновение ржавчины.

Comment: Предложение содержит противоречие.  Может быть, надо было написать "[Особо] важными технологическими этапами являются...", потому как "одними" как-то странно звучит.

Comment: Тоже хорошее решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Одним из важных технологических этапов являются покраска шарового
>   крана и нанесение средств...

***Одними из наиболее важных*** технологических этапов являются покраска шарового крана и нанесение средств...

Comment: Спасибо большое!